# Automatically run Travis-ci with svn repo?

Tags: git, svn, github, travis-ci

Is it possible to run travis-ci using a svn repo the same way as github is used?

It seems that I can only trigger a rebuild when there is a push to github - but would it be possible to setup a script which triggers a push or a rebuild whenever the svn repo has changed, or mirror the svn repo automatically to github?

Comment: See this, it may help https://danielpocock.com/automatically-mirroring-svn-repositories-to-git-and-github/ and this https://github.com/esplinr/svn-github-mirrors

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a direct solution, but one could mirror the svn repo to GitHub and trigger a rebuild from there.

Comment: I look for a step-by-step instruction how to do it, starting from the mirror process (which I assume, according to the bounty description, to be the only way). Maybe you want to try to answer your own question by going down the road?